# Regular expression in bash or sed

Tags: php, regex, bash, ubuntu, sed

I have a regular expression (PHP) to clean the string from file:

```
return  preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9  \n \)\(\,\%\\@\!?\#\&\;\'\"\-\+.\/"]/','', $string);
```

I'm using Ubuntu and want to clean the file content using bash or sed?
How can I do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: Please share what you tried to see how we can help you.

Comment: What does *to clean* mean here? What's wrong with the current solution?

Comment: Current solution uses php. I'm looking for something using Ubuntu

Comment: You can use the same regex with `sed`. Copy and paste it.

Comment: You can run PHP code in command line using "-r": `php -r 'echo preg_replace("/o/","e", "foot")."\n";'`. Your code has many quotes, you will have to escape them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Remove non-ASCII characters

You appear to simply want to strip out non-ASCII characters (though you're missing each of `` $*:<=>[]^_`{|}~ `` and I don't know if that's intentional). There are several ways to do this, including a command written for this express purpose.

- `strings FILENAME`
- `tr -cd '[\t\r\n -~]' < FILENAME`
- `sed 's/[^\t\r\n -~]//g' FILENAME`

The `strings` utility does this automatically and is great for quickly checking the contents of a binary file with safe output for the terminal. You may dislike the way it separates blocks of text with line breaks.

The other two commands take a list of characters (including ranges by character code) and removes them. In `tr` (short for "translate"), the `-c` option gets the complement of the list and the `-d` means delete matches rather than translating them. In `sed` (short for "streamline editor"), I'm running a `s///` substitution on an inverted [character set](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) like the one you used in your PHP code and replacing each match (the `/g` flag matches **g**lobally) with an empty string.

The character set (okay, technically that's not the right term for `tr` usage, e.g. you can't negate it like `[^…]`, but that's why we use `tr -c`) calls out a few white space characters (tab, carriage return, line feed) and then specifies the range of characters from space () to tilde (`~`), covered by the codes U+0020 to U+007e.

You may run across `[!-~]` as well. That's shorthand for all printable ASCII characters. Spaces are not printable, which is why I had to name them explicitly, though at least the space character (U+0020) immediately precedes exclamation (`!`, U+0021) so I could just lump that into our range.

### Remove just your listed characters

This requires preserving the list, though I can collapse it taking advantage of any contiguous character codes:

```sh
sed 's/[^\t\r\n -#%-)+-9;?-Z\\a-z]//g' FILENAME
```

[Explanation of above regex](https://regex101.com/r/jvZLl7/2/). Compare it to [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/jvZLl7/1/) or to the [more comprehensive non-ASCII regex](https://regex101.com/r/jvZLl7/4) from the previous section (I added Latin-1 Supplemental to that last link's test set so you can see that it actually matches something).

### In place

If you want to save to the same file, you can run `sed -i COMMAND FILENAME` using either of the `s///` commands listed above.